# Matlab Image Processing Using for Loop to detect a coordinate

Tags: image, matlab, for-loop

I want to execute a logical statement in a for loop.

If I have an image of size 480(height) by 640(width), I would like to scan the image in a section, this section being the whole height between width 635 to 640. I would like to find out if there are any (x,y) coordinates which are found in the cell "cellData". This cell contains a whole list of (x,y) coordinates which can be found in the whole image.

```
h = height
w = width
for h = 1:480
    for w = 635:640
        if cellData = 1;
            cellData(x,y) = SecondCoordinate(x,y);
        end
    end
end
```

Basically I am trying to select a point in the section I mentioned above. The point must be from the cell "cellData". Am i doing this correctly? Will the first (x,y) coordinates that the code detects from the cellData be stored as a (x,y) coordinate in "SecondCoordinate(x,y)"?

Comment: You need to clarify your code and post. You probably mean `== 1` instead of `= 1`. Plus: you state that `cellData` is a list of (x,y) pairs, but you compare it to an integer. Which is it?

Comment: If I am comparing it to an integer, it means that I am doing it wrongly, which was my question to begin with. If you understand from the code, what I am actually looking for in that section is the first (x,y) coordinates which can be found between the height and width I mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

You should have a look at [find](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/find.html). It's not only much shorter, but also more efficient than your current approach with nested for loops.

`[row, col] = find(cellData)` would return all the coordinates where `cellData` is not zero.

If cellData contains other values than just ones and zeros, it would be

```
[row, col] = find(cellData ~= 0)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. however, if I would only like to return the first coordinates of "cellData" that the nested for loops find, and not all, what should my approach be?

Comment: @Melvyn, `[row, col] = find(cellData, 1, 'first')` should do exactly that.